# redux tookit when using a middleware builder function, an array of middleware must be returned

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

So I'm getting `Uncaught Error: when using a middleware builder function, an array of middleware must be returned`

This is my code

```js
import {
  configureStore,
  compose,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);
const composeWithDevTools = 
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const composedMiddleWare = composeWithDevTools(middleware)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: composedMiddleWare,
  devTools: 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
})

export default store;
```

I have no idea what's wrong and searching doesn't seem to be returning any useful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configureStore` from `redux-toolkit` (RTK) works differently from the `redux` `createStore` function. The `middleware` property accepts an array of middleware to install and RTK handles applying them.

See [configureStore](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore)

> ```
> /**
>  * An array of Redux middleware to install. If not supplied, defaults to
>  * the set of middleware returned by `getDefaultMiddleware()`.
>  */
> middleware?: ((getDefaultMiddleware: CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware<S>) => M) | M
> ```

Note that while [`applyMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#applymiddleware) is re-exported from `redux` that

> You should not need to use this directly.

The following would be the code you'd use:

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk], // <-- array of middlewares to install/apply
  devTools: window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
});

export default store;
```

RTK also ships with opinionated optimizations:

1. The [`devTools`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#devtools) are enabled by default, you'll only use this if you have custom needs.
2. Thunk middleware is also already included with the [default middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#included-default-middleware), e.g. if no `middleware` property is provided, then [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) is provided and returns the following middleware value, which includes the `thunk` middleware:

   ```js
   const middleware = [
     actionCreatorInvariant,
     immutableStateInvariant,
     thunk, // <-- included thunk middleware!
     serializableStateInvariant,
   ]
   ```

   Again, you'll really only need to specify the `middleware` property if you need to customize the [immutability](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/immutabilityMiddleware) or [serialization](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) middlewares.

Your store configuration can be reduced to the following:

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

Both the thunk middleware and dev tools will be active and working.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Drew. I learnt a lot from your answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is caused by the incorrect usage of the `applyMiddleware` function from Redux. In Redux Toolkit, the `configureStore` function already applies the middleware internally, so you don't need to use `applyMiddleware` separately.

Here's the corrected code:

```
 import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
 import thunk from "redux-thunk";

 const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

 const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
 });

 export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

from this line

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({});
```

the array is empty it cannot be empty us have to put in a slice. for example if you want to use a userSlice, the you have to add it there like this:

```
import { configureStore, compose, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 
"@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {userSlice} from './userSlice.js'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({userSlice});
```

notice i add a userSlice to the array

Comment: the userSlice i added is imaginary so you have to create a userSlice.js as a state for your users

Comment: The Error is about the middleware though. I know reducer is empty but right now the execution is getting stuck at middleware